# Chrome video decoding GPU or CPU

Tags: video, codec, nvidia, decoding

If I watch a video on the internet in the chrome browser, and the video is encoded with H265 or VP9 (or the future AV1), and I have a Nvidia GPU (GTX 1080): Is the video decoding happening on the GPU or the CPU? (I have hardware acceleration enabled in chrome)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like the Hardware Acceleration's enabled in your Chrome as you wrote above.

> ***When hardware acceleration is enabled in Chrome, the browser passes most of the graphical intensive tasks within the browser to the GPU, meaning it makes the most of your hardware.***

References:

- [How to Turn Hardware Acceleration On and Off in Chrome](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122)

Answer (score 0):

Actually GPU acceleration is hardware-dependent and also old GPU drivers can cause problems. On GTX 1080 with recent drivers you have "complete acceleration of VP9 profile 2 (10-bit) and maximum resolution of up to 8192 x 8192 pixels (8k resolution) for all HEVC and VP9 profiles." For av1 decoding you have to rely on CPU solely as the Feature Set K of PureVideo is introduced with GTX 3080. ([Source url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160892)